# How do you use Attributes with Windows Authentication / Authorisation when there isn't a roles table?

Tags: c#, authentication, attributes, authorization, asp.net-mvc-5

I have asked a similar question before but I think it wasn't quite on the mark:

[How to create users and store them in a database and link them to windows authentication logins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20619418/how-to-create-users-and-store-them-in-a-database-and-link-them-to-windows-authen)

I have a client that would like the following authentication/authorisation scenario set up:

1. They would like an intranet site
2. All users must be authenticated by Windows in order to see the application (ASP.NET MVC 4.0)
3. Roles (authorisation) for the users will be defined inside the application by Admins, more specifically, an Admin will have access to a page called "Manage Users" where he can select from a list of Windows usernames, add a first name and last name and select whether he is an Admin or not. The result of which is a User entered into a SQL database.

I am aware of the Windows authentication approach whereby you add:

```
<authentication mode="Windows"></authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

to the **Web.config** file and select "enabled" from the Windows Authentication dropdown. This certainly deals with the requirement to be logged into Windows... but now for the authorisation.

The real issue for me is that I also am aware of the awesome authorisation attributes provided by default in c# ASP .NET. To clarify, an example usage of this would be:

```
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    [Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Well, here lies the problem. I am yet to have defined who is and who is not an "Admin", or for that matter a "Member", "Author"... but let's leave the custom roles out for now (hmm jam roles).

**To further clarify**, I would imagine I would have a table of User_Roles

```
UserName          | Role   | RelatedProfileID
---------------------------------------------
DOMAIN\John.Smith | Admin  | ~    
DOMAIN\Bob.Yazoo  | Member | ~
```

whereby RelatedProfileID relates to a Profile table containing FirstName and LastName entries for that user.

So when the user comes in, I do a lookup on their username in my database... find out what role they have and show elements on the site based off of their role. And on a controller level, I would add the attribute tags for example:

```
public class NonsenseController : Controller
{
    [Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
    public ActionResult OnlyAdmins()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Authorize(Roles="Member")]        
    public ViewResult OnlyMembers()
    {
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance guys!

*There is just one more clarification needed before a flurry of eager stackoverflowalites come to answer my question.*

- *One of the administrators (my main client contact) is the administrator of the database that will be used for this intranet site...*

*He would like to be able to add windows authenticated users to the SQL database which in turn may arise to issues with authentication; he may change the database roles of one of the windows users to be full admin... and yet in the application, forgets to change the role of that user to "Admin" too... What do you think about this particular problem in context with the question?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to sum up:

- You want to use windows authentication
- The authorisation is defined by roles, which are configured is a sql database
- You want to be able to use the authorisation attributes.

This article should explain everything you need: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/07/23/Recipe_3A00_-Implementing-Role-Based-Security-with-ASP.NET-using-Windows-Authentication-and-SQL-Server.aspx

EDIT: 19/12/2013 - Getting at a list of users

To get a list of users sql membership provider. You have a couple of options:

- Write code to get information from AD. This article tells you almost everything you need for this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C
- Using the ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.activedirectorymembershipprovider(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I have managed to get this to work... but am slightly confused now.. When you get to the part like this: Roles.AddUserToRole(@"JIMMYT1988\jimmyt1988", "Admin"); I now see my database with a user in the aspnet_Users dataase table... but when I call upon Membership.GetAllUsers it returns an empty list? any ideas?

Comment: Do you have an entry in the aspnet_Membership table?

Comment: No, and this is the issue. the Membership.CreateUser method requires me to supply a password... and yet, this is an intranet application.. so I really don't need a password... But I still need to get a list of all Users who currently have access to the application or who have been assigned to a role at the very least. I think i'm using the wrong set of classes but I don't know what the correct ones are.

Comment: basically (following on from the article you sent me): I want to create roles for windows authorised users and store that user_role relation in the database (DONE), and now I want to get a list of all users who have access to the application.

Comment: Ok I see - when you say all users who have access, do you mean all users that have a role, or all users in active directory?

Comment: Not all users will have a role and yet they need to be listed...soo.. yea I guess "active directory" which is the missing part of the puzzle. Do you happen to know how to get that list?

Comment: You wont be able to use the sql membership provider for that. You have a couple of options - either write code to get information from AD (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C) or you could try using the ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.activedirectorymembershipprovider(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Simply put, and for anyone stumbling upon this; OP misunderstood what Windows Authentication means and wanted to store AD information like roles in a separate roll-your-own database. By mixing these two concepts, nothing worked out. In the end, OP simply needed to use the built-in AD functionality instead of reinventing the wheel.